# Spring MVC WebApp Issue

Tags: multithreading, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

We are using Spring MVC 3 for our WebApplication. I see a strange behavior from the application. When a user perform a action (ex: button click) , i see the controllers logs are logged twice and so are the subsequent calls in the controller .Controllers we used are default,singleton.
 So,

1. I would like to print the thread information in the controller(like threadName.   tried      Thread.getName()..was Unique).. any help?
2. How do i make sure that there is only one Spring container
   loaded? -- any Suggestions?

log4j Prop:

```
    `log4j.appender.ROLL_FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
     log4j.appender.ROLL_FILE.File=/ws/was/dept/logs/${module.jvm.instance}_module.log
     log4j.appender.ROLLING_FILE.Append=true 
     log4j.additivity.ROLLING_FILE.Append=false 
     log4j.appender.ROLLING_FILE.MaxFileSize=10MB 
     log4j.appender.ROLLING_FILE.MaxBackupIndex=20 
     log4j.appender.ROLLING_FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
     log4j.appender.ROLLING_FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=[module] %d - %c -%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m
```

Web.xml :

```
<display-name>module</display-name>
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>classpath*:/spring/int/root-int-context.xml,/WEB-INF/spring/root-  context.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
<listener>
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
      <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet.xml</param-value>
      </init-param>          
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>`
   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
 ..........
 .........
 .........
```

Thanks

Comment: are you using a logging library?

Comment: More likely it's logging framework issue logging the same messages twice. Do you use Logback or Log4J? Can you share your configuration? Put a breakpoint in the controller, I bet it will be hit only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `Thread.getId()` to get the unique thread ID.
2. Check your logger configuration - I'm guessing you are using `log4j` or `slfj` - you might have more than one logger that intercepts the message adds appenders on-top of the appenders defined in the parent logger this might cause two messages to be printed - so check if you have that and define `additivity` to be false.

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to print the thread information in the controller(like threadName. tried Thread.getName()..was Unique)*

- Use a logging framework. You can find several examples. Check [here](http://crazygui.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/configure-logback-logging-with-spring/) for configuring logback

*How do i make sure that there is only one Spring container loaded?*

- I really don't understand what you mean here, but if have defined contextConfigLocation appropriately in your web.xml, the Spring container would be loaded correctly

  ```
  <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>
      classpath*:/META-INF/spring/*.xml 
  </param-value>
  ```